# Android Accessibility onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo not called

Tags: android, kotlin, customization, accessibility

I created a custom tab view and I am attempting to set up the correct accessibility for this custom view.  Within the Fragment's *onViewCreated*, I am setting the desired roleDescription:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.customViewFoo.also { customViewFoo ->
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(customViewFoo,
            object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info)
                    info.roleDescription = "Custom View Foo"
                }
            })
    }
}
```

However, the function *onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo* is not being called.  Looking at [Android Accessibility — Resolving common Talkback issues](https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/android-accessibility-resolving-common-talkback-issues-3c45076bcdf6) in the Roles section, I don't see a difference between my code and her example other than her example is set within an Activity.  I also looked at the [Make Custom Views More Accessible](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/custom-views) on the Android site and it says pretty much the same thing.

Thoughts on what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm on time, but this may help someone else. Honestly, I'm not totally sure this is what helped, because I was trying to solve the same problem in a very big project, but it seems so to me.

Try adding this line in your xml view file, you want to set accessible.

`android:importantForAccessibility="yes"`

Without this property set my application was trying to handle accessibility options via `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` method, after adding this line it seems to have started to add the delegate first and than reacting to the event with `dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent` if still needed. But I repeat, that I'm not 100% sure this is the solution.